# Why does route rule not work when I set mark after the net packet go through the 'forward chain' of iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

I want to that all the packets through 'farword chain' redirect to local loopback, so that  I can proxy this traffic.
I set the route rules of iproute2 (all the packet with mark 1 is routed to local loopback),and then set mark 1 for packet in FORWARD chain of iptables. The content is as follows:

PS:
When I set mark 1 for packet in PREROUTING chain of iptables, this route rule works ok. But it does not work in FORWARD chain of iptables. I don't know the reason.

```
// OS System: 

# iptables -V
iptables v1.4.21

# uname -a
Linux centos7 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 19 16:18:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

//set mark 1 route rule

# ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
# ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100

# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup 100
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip route list table 100
local default dev lo scope host


// set mark 1 in FORWARD chain

# iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 169.254.2.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 1

# iptables -nL -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
UTPROXY    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
LOG        tcp  --  192.168.11.1         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "pre:"

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        tcp  --  192.168.11.1         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "input:"

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            169.254.2.0/24       MARK set 0x1
LOG        tcp  --  192.168.11.1         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "forward:"

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.11.1         tcp spt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "output:"

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.11.1         tcp spt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "post:"
LOG        tcp  --  192.168.11.1         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "post:"

Chain UTPROXY (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
TPROXY     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            169.254.2.0/24       TPROXY redirect 0.0.0.0:2001 mark 0x1/0x1
```

[This is the iptables work proccess,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmEzD.png)

[This is the iptables log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6ag8.png)

Comment: Because that's how it work by design? Even the chain name tells you, "pre" "routing". So are you just looking for details on how it is designed to work? Or do you for some reason "need" the rule in the FORWARD chain instead? (XY problem?)

Comment: According to the iptables documentation(Chapter 6. Traversing of tables and chains), after the network data packet passes through the forward chain, the routing table will be judged again. But  it did not take effect. [iptables docment](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#TRAVERSINGOFTABLES)

Comment: The problem is the moment you set the mark isn't the same moment as the traffics with the mark is matched against the ip rule. If you need to *change* the the routing *decision*, you need to change it "in/with" the iptables rule. (The mark probably won't matter anymore/again once the initial routing decision has been made.)

Comment: I wouldn't be too surprised even if it works like this: saying you set the mark in prerouting and triggered a routing decision change in mangle forward (saying by changing the destination with some non-NAT method would do), I'm not so sure it would even use route(s) in the alternate route table that the mark once led the traffics to. Since I have no idea in what niche situation you'd need something like that, I am not gonna comment whether that should be considered a bug/flaw. (And in my experience, you can't expect everything to be really rock solid when policy routing is involved.)

Comment: Thanks， I don't notice that the tables is different from the map figure in the iptables document.